# Is there a way to scrape the dataLayer available on the page instead of the regular HTML Elements in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fetch some data from the web pages using Excel `VBA` and have been fairly successful.

However I have realized that most of the pages do have data-layer available on the page and thus if I am able to use the same, lot of effort can be reduced in massaging the data to bring it in usable format.

I tried to call the data layer by `Document.getElement` method but this seems not to be working.

I am not a hard core developer just can swim for my needs so please let me know if this is possible as all of my search results so far have yielded nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use SeleniumBasic (Excel Plugin) for WebScraping Needs. They way it can be done is by using

```
driver.ExecuteScript("return dataLayer[x].variableName")
```